# How to display image in a container full screen (Behind scaffold from other class)?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, containers

I tried to use state management, but I completely do not understand that how to implement it into my code. So I tried to work around it by myself and came up with the idea to make new class with the button and background but to have these behind the other class? It works, as in when I press the button the image changes and the other items on page keep their state (Do not change) but the problem is that the image in as big as the row of buttons and not entire screen. When I do use another scaffold in the rowwidget class then I'm getting overflow rendering errors.

```
class CustomMainPageState extends State<SecondRoute> {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 130),
                Container(
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                  child: Text(
                    "${Provider.of<TaskData>(context).rann()}",
                    //softWrap: true,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    //textWidthBasis: TextWidthBasis.longestLine,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 80),
                timerry(),
                SizedBox(height: 60),
                Rowwidget(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class Rowwidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const Rowwidget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Rowwidget> createState() => _RowwidgetState();
}

class _RowwidgetState extends State<Rowwidget> {
  String _imagepath1 = "images/image3.jpg";

  String _imagepath2 = "images/image4.jpg";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(_imagepath1), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
      child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 25,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Image.asset('images/ForestIcon.png'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _imagepath1 = _imagepath2;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;


  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String img_path = 'images/image3.jpg';

  void _onTap(String path) {
    setState(() {
      img_path = path;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(img_path), fit: BoxFit.fill)),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 130),
                Container(
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                  child: Text(
                    "Sample text",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 80),
                SizedBox(height: 60),
                Rowwidget(onTap: _onTap),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class Rowwidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const Rowwidget({Key? key, required this.onTap}) : super(key: key);

  final callOnTap onTap;

  @override
  State<Rowwidget> createState() => _RowwidgetState();
}

class _RowwidgetState extends State<Rowwidget> {
  String _imagepath1 = "images/image3.jpg";
  String _imagepath2 = "images/image4.jpg";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 25,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Image.asset('images/ForestIcon.png'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _imagepath1 = _imagepath2;
                    widget.onTap(_imagepath1);
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}

typedef callOnTap(String path);
```

Comment: Hi there, It is also causing some overflowing ``"======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 181 pixels on the bottom."``

Comment: try to use Expanded widget,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did use it and it's causing this error.

Comment: I have updated the code above, try it, no errors, not using timerry() Widget

Comment: Hi there, Ok without the timerry(); its getting there, however i cant seem to make it full screen the image now, any idea?

Comment: I have updated again the code, now it shows the image full screen, check

Comment: hi there, did you checked the update? I move the state to upper widget

Comment: Hi, just checked the update and it works great now, but my main thing was to keep the state outside in other class (When I do change picture with this updated code it rebuilds that class which I forgot that I have text `"${Provider.of<TaskData>(context).rann()}",` which rebuilds it self when i change picture. Any idea how to move the state back to lower widget so it will work ? Thank you so much !

Comment: Hi, I have moved the state again down in the tree, code updated, check plz

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help, unfortunately, when I click the button to change the pic, it rebuilds the text provider aswell. Not sure why since the state is in different class :(